# Listview inside fragment crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have just began with android and am trying to create a tabbed layout with listview in its fragments. Whats the best option.?
I have tried below which worked:
1.  making custom adapter for listview 
2.   two-tab action bar layout with dummy fragments
When I tried using listview activity as a fragment, the app crashes. I have pasted the code below.
App concept:  Ticket Booking app!. For this I have created a Movie class which holds  Movie name, category and review details. MovieManager makes a list of movies.  The app crashes while opening a fragment activity which holds the movi e list in different categories [tabs].

**Activity that crashes the app while opening:**

//Activity that contains the movie list in separate categories
public class AllMovies extends FragmentActivity  {

```
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";
ListViewHollyLV;
ListViewBollyLV;
ListViewKollyLV;

private void ListCreater()
  {
    HollyLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.bollyListView1);
    newMovieListActivity().CurrentLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.bollyListView1);
  }


  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_movies);

        ListCreater();


    // Set up the action bar to show tabs.
finalActionBaractionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // for each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.hello_world).setTabListener(new TabListener( this, "holly", MovieListActivity.class));     
actionBar.addTab(tab); 
tab = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.hello_world).setTabListener(new TabListener( this, "bolly", Fragi2.class));     
actionBar.addTab(tab); 
  }


static class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {     
    private Fragment mFragment;     
    private final Activity mActivity;     
    private final String mTag;     
    private final Class mClass;      

      /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.       
       * * @paramactivity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment       
       * * @paramtag  The identifier tag for the fragment       
       * * @paramclz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment       
       * */     

    publicTabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class clz) 
      {         mActivity = activity;         
    mTag = tag;         
    mClass = clz;     }      

      /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */      

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransactionft) {         
          // Check if the fragment is already initialized         
        if (mFragment == null) {            
              // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity             
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());             
            ft.add(R.id.fragmentCnt, mFragment, mTag);         
              } 
        else {             
              // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it            
            ft.attach(mFragment);         
              }    
          }      
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransactionft)
      {        
        if (mFragment != null) {         
              // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached          
            ft.detach(mFragment);        
              }  
      }
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransactionft) {      
          // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.    
          }         
      }

//This fragment is used for “holly” tab
public static class MovieListActivity extends Fragment {

    ListViewCurrentLV;  


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflaterinflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag1, container, false);
    ManageMovieList.MakeList(); // Makes separate list of Hollywood and bollywood //movies
    LoadMovieList();

return V;

    }               

    @Override 
    public void onPause() {     
        super.onPause(); 

    }       
    //Loads the Hollywood movie list to the listview using custom adapter
    private void LoadMovieList()
    {
        ManageMovieList.HollywoodMovieAdapter(getActivity(), CurrentLV);
    }       
}

/// Dummy Fragment class (was created while trying tabbed layout) which contains only ///textview. Still this fragment is used for “bolly” tab

public static class Fragi1 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflaterinflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag1, container, false);

return V;

    }
}
```

}

**Custom Adapter**

public class CustomMovieArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
private final Context context;
ArrayList<Movie> _Movies ;
static final String REVIEW = "com.example.ticketonline";


publicCustomMovieArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie>movieItems) {
    super(context, R.layout.movie_list_item, movieItems);
    this.context = context;
    _Movies = movieItems;
    Movie currentMovie = new Movie();
    ArrayList<Movie> _Movies ;
}

String Title;
String category;
int Id;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflaterinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

    if (convertView == null) { 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_list_item, parent, false);

    TextViewtextName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieName);
    TextViewtextCate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMovieCategory);
    ImageViewimageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMoviePoster);
    Button btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectMovie);

    textName.setText(_Movies.get(position).GetMovieName(position));
    textCate.setText(_Movies.get(position).GetMovieCategory(position));
    imageView.setImageResource(_Movies.get(position).GetMoviePosterID(position));   

    finalint p = position;
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReviewAndBook.class);    
intent.putExtra(REVIEW, Movie.GetMovieReview(p));
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Movie.GetMovieDirector(p));
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, Movie.GetMovieCast(p));
context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    }

    returnconvertView;
}
```

}

**The method  which resides in MovieManager class**

```
     public static void HollywoodMovieAdapter(Context cnt,ListViewmovieListUI)
{
    //ListViewmovieListUI = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.movieListView);
    ArrayList<Movie> _hollywoodMovies = ManageMovieList.RecentMovies_Holly;
    movieListUI.setAdapter( new CustomMovieArrayAdapter(cnt, _hollywoodMovies));    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common issue that I have seen in my limited experience is that a hard-to-detect bug might originate in the fragment layout xml file.  If there are, for example, any "circular references" (easy to do with a RelativeLayout) your app might run but will crash when you open the fragment that uses that xml. This kind of crash isn't really specified in the Logcat, it would point you to a line of code in your fragment that doesn't actually have a problem.  The reason that line of code created a logcat error might be from a mistake in your layout xml file.